# why isn't my mysqli statment working in flex 4.5?

Tags: php, mysqli, flash-builder, prepared-statement

hi there i'm working with flex 4.5 and php, i have a services php file with a query that is actually workink this query retreives an specific product info. but when i want to get the statement with like?% is not working here is the working code

```
public function getProductsByName2($searchStr) {
     $stmt = mysqli_prepare($this->connection,
          "SELECT
              products.id,
              products.codb,
              products.nombre,
              products.precio,
              products.cantidad
           FROM products where products.nombre LIKE ?");
      $this->throwExceptionOnError();


      mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's', $searchStr);
```

this code actually works gets an specific product information but must match exactly the name , if i want to retrieve all names starting with "c" for example i should have something like this

```
public function getProductsByName2($searchStr) {
     $stmt = mysqli_prepare($this->connection,
          "SELECT
              products.id,
              products.codb,
              products.nombre,
              products.precio,
              products.cantidad
           FROM products where products.nombre LIKE CONCAT('%',?,'%')");
      $this->throwExceptionOnError();


      mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's', $searchStr);
```

but somehow is not working please any help is appreciated

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, this question has nothing to do with Flex, nor Flash Builder?  It's more of a "how do I query the database with PHP" question, right?  I removed the Flex tags and added PHP.

Answer (score 0):

I have never seen the "%" added with MYSQL's CONCAT-Method. Rather, I'd add the `%` within the PHP scope - so:

```
// ...
FROM products where products.nombre LIKE ?");
// ...
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's', '%' . $searchStr . '%');
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: nope :( im getting so desperated i also tried
    $searchStr=$searchStr . '%';
        mysql_stmt_bind_param($stmt,'s',$se...); and nothing
@Lukx

Comment: by the way sorry for editing your post but i don't know how to make sure you're getting updates from this thread